# Use current date of ArcGIS time slider as date input in query builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, query, timeslider

I'm trying to formulate a query in ArcGIS query builder, returning only Features present in a certain year. The year should be definable by the user by setting the date in the time slider.

My Problem is that I should do this for 5 different layers. Layer 1 showing the Features of the current year set in the time slider, layer 2 showing the Features of the current year (time slider) + 1, layer 3 showing the Features of the current year (time slider) +2 etc.

I managed to do so using sysdate (code for the current year (sysdate) + 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM FC
WHERE:
trunc(START_DATE, 'YEAR') <=  trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR') + INTERVAL '1' year
AND
trunc(END_DATE, 'YEAR') >= trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR') + INTERVAL '1' year
```

But now I should find a solution to get the time slider date instead of the sysdate. 
Is this possible? Or are there more elegant approaches to solve this Problem?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.6 Desktop and Database is Oracle.